# How do I register a Tomcat 7.0.41 server on NetBeans 7.3?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, web-applications, netbeans

I have just downloaded NetBeans 7.3 for JavaEE and installed it with Tomcat 7.0.41 Everything went fine and I can run NetBeans, start and stop Tomcat from within the IDE and add and remove servers at will.

However when I try and create a Java web Application project my server list is empty.

The message I get at the bottom of the wizard for creating projects is "**No servers are registered in the IDE. To register a server, click the "Add..." button**.

I have Googled and got nothing and looked at the NetBeans docs and got nothing, help me

I am running **Netbeans 7.3, Java 1.7, Tomcat 7.0.41** and Windows xp-3.

Comment: What happened when you clicked the "Add..." button as suggested?

Comment: it is asked again to add server only

Comment: Then select your tomcat installation and go through the wizard.

Comment: fine but again problem is repeated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Problem is solved by just `Restarted` Netbeans Software 
Thanks to all

Comment: I just had the same problem. Restarting Netbeans didn't work, but restarting my computer did. Very frustrating, thanks for helping to point me in the right direction, I didn't think I'd set anything up incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

I know the original problem was solved, but I had a very similar issue, and in my case simply restarting Netbeans did not help, so I wanted to help anyone with my issue.  It sounds stupid, but I wanted to warn people that they need to be sure to download the right tomcat zip file.

Tomcat lists several zip files on their server, and I should have been using the Windows-64 zip file.  Instead, I downloaded the first file, which just said "zip".  I am not sure what configuration this was.  It ran in windows 7, but created the same sort of mysterious pattern in Netbeans.  In the Services tab, I could clearly see Apache Tomcat listed under Servers.  If I started the service it worked fine.  However, when I right clicked on my project and attempted to resolve missing server problem, it would not list tomcat in the list.  The list is filtered to only show servers that are valid with the version of Java EE 6 or whatever you are using.  In my case, apparently the original tomcat I downloaded was not valid.

Answer (score 1):

You have to register the server inside Netbeans. 
Simply a matter of going to the servers tab under tools & adding a new server & browsing to the installation location.

Follow the tutorial on the link below here (start at the time I have set): 
[Tutorial](http://youtu.be/S5aIyaoSJBg?t=30m49s)

Comment: i have done the your given way but when ever the application is going to be created that shows the No servers are registered in the IDE. To register a server, click the "Add..." button. error

Answer (score 0):

Try this remove all server from the IDE and then double click the netbeans exe go to customize select the the tomcat server alone and then install

[sample](https://ui.netbeans.org/docs/hi/nbi/nbi-ui-spec.html#Installer_Welcome)

Comment: i have already got this link, it is working fine but when ever try to add web app in netbeans it is showing that error

Comment: try this remove all server from the IDE and then double click the netbeans exe go to customize select the the tomcat server alone and then install

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Tools -> Plugin -> Update Plugin`.Worked for me, give it a try.