# No server registered in NEtbeans IDE . To register click ADD.....

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat7, netbeans-7

I am getting above error on creating new web project.Even I configured and added glass fish and tomcat server in netbeans. Even I tried to remove Glass Fish server from IDE & restarted.But still error persists.I have installed Netbeans 7.3 IDE on ubuntu12.4  OS.
Kindly provide solution to problem.I am unable to create new web project.

I even tried all suggestions mention on the link- [How do I register a Tomcat 7.0.41 server on NetBeans 7.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357963/how-do-i-register-a-tomcat-7-0-41-server-on-netbeans-7-3)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try NetBeans 7.4? Did you file an issue at netbeans.org/bugzilla/ ?

Comment: Thanks.I resolved the problem by setting permissions of Ubuntu OS.  I started **Netbeans IDE** as **root user** by command line  -   sudo -i -> run Netbeans

Answer (score -1):

I resolved the problem by setting permissions of Ubuntu OS.  I started **Netbeans IDE** as **root user** by command line  -   sudo -i -> run Netbeans

Comment: This may have fixed your issue, but I'm going to frown on this.  You should **never** run arbitrary programs as root.  You should **only** run programs that absolutely *require* root as such.  I'm more than convinced that there is another issue in your setup; make sure that the folder you're using Netbeans from belongs to your user.