# Netbeans 7.3 unable to register server Tomcat 7.0.41

Tags: java, netbeans

Whenever I try to open a Java web application in netbeans IDE, it shows an error message : "No servers are registered in the IDE". But I have added it. I have used Apache Tomcat and GlassFish server too. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357963/how-do-i-register-a-tomcat-7-0-41-server-on-netbeans-7-3

Comment: Also this:- https://forums.netbeans.org/ntopic5964.html and specially:
"Afaik GFv3 plugin (not sure about the GF runtime) allows only web apps so 
far. You need GFv2 if you want to create enterprise application. "